# Apply manual update on Xoom without an OTG cable

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, motorola-xoom, usb-host-mode

So the ICS update [came out for Xoom](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-and-install-official-android-4.0.3-ics-update-on-motorola-xoom-manually-how-to/) and applying it is straight forward enough - pretty much like in any other case. Except, it seems to require the OTG cable.

Would anybody know a way to do that without using such cable? I mean, applying the patch either from the internal memory or from the sd mount?

Comment: From what I have read, the Xoom will not update from a update.zip file from an SD card/internal storage. Without the cable you will have to wait for an OTA update.

Comment: In case it's a matter of not having a cable, you can buy one on [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=micro+usb+otg) for less than US $1 (with shipping)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you live in non-US country, then you can follow a guide for installing the US-based ICS on you Xoom [that I've written up on my blog](http://techcoze.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/motorola-xoom-wi-fi-mz604-ice-cream-sandwich-4-0-3-ota-update-in-non-us-countries/). The basic procedure is:

> 1. Install Android SDK and Motorola USB drivers on your PC
> 2. Download US honeycomb stock ROM from [here](http://developer.motorola.com/products/software/MZ604_HWI69.zip/)
> 3. Extract all files from this ZIP file into platform-tools folder under Android SDK
> 4. Boot the device into fastboot mode.
> 5. Then from command prompt (with current directory ‘sdk/platform-tools’) run following commands-
>
>    1. fastboot oem unlock  (this is red pill, at this point your device warranty voids! welcome to matrix!!)
>    2. fastboot flash boot boot.img
>    3. fastboot flash system system.img
>    4. fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
>    5. fastboot flash userdata userdata.img
>    6. fastboot erase cache
> 6. now reboot the device
> 7. go to settings -> about -> update, this will download subsequent ROM update and will install it, and then reboot
> 8. repeat step-7 until all updates are done (will normally need 4-5 update cycles)

Note that it will void your device warranty

Comment: I've edited your post to indicate that the website you linked to is your own blog. Please note the [FAQ section on self-promotion](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) in the future. Also note that I've summarized the basic premise of your blog post here. Answers with unexplained links are considered less useful due to linkrot and the like, so providing a summary rather than simply a link is preferred.

Comment: For anyone following this, note that the first step in step 5 (unlocking the bootloader) will likely wipe your device, make sure that you back up any data you care about on your device first.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the Xoom do you have? Motorola have so far only released an ICS update for the US Wifi version of the Xoom (the 3G version and the International version use different firmware and haven't had the update yet, applying this update to those models may harm them).

If you do have a US Wifi Xoom then Motorola are [already actively pushing this update out](https://forums.motorola.com/posts/8e67ccfce4) and have been doing this in batches since 24th Jan. If your device is regularly connected to the internet and hasn't automatically picked up the update yet, then you can force it to go and check by going into **Settings** -> **About tablet** and selecting **System updates** it should then go and check for you.

In the future, if you want to have a chance of getting Xoom updates early, you can join the official [Motorola Feedback Network](https://forums.motorola.com/posts/77d4221775), members of that group did reportedly get the ICS update a few weeks earlier than everyone else. Join it by signing up at the [Motorola Forums](http://forums.motorola.com) and selecting the "Motorola Feedback Network" option.

If you do want to do this manual update, then you can pick up a USB OTG (aka Host Mode USB cable) very cheaply on eBay, I got one for connecting my camera to the Xoom for a couple of pounds, including postage from Hong Kong!

Comment: I do have a Wifi Xoom, though is the UK version (MZ604). Since you used "pounds" to get your OTG cable, I'd assume you are the same. Did you try the update? (Seen in a page from motorola, but can't find it now, anyway they didn't show any plan to update us to ICS OTA)

Comment: @flpgdt the non-US version is different, has slightly different software loaded and uses different drivers. The US version is a "Google Experience Device" the International ones aren't, this is why we've got some Motorola and other software pre-loaded (MotoPrint, Citrix Receiver, etc) and also why write access to our SD card was fixed before it was on the US version. I haven't tried the update on mine, as I've seen such mixed success from people trying US updates on their non-US Xooms with previous updates, as well as losing functionality (like the SD Card) when they put the US image on.

Comment: Hm.. I see. found this article might be of use. Although it requires to install US version, later you'd get ICS, which I reckon would make it up. http://futureproof10.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/motorola-xoom-wi-fi-mz604-ice-cream-sandwich-4-0-3-ota-update-in-non-us-countries/